# Regex for timestamps in php

Tags: php, regex, time

I'm trying to take timestamps in this format:

2009-11-16T14:05:22-08:00

and make turn them into something like

2009-11-16

How do I remove everything after the "T"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
list($date) = explode('T', '2009-11-16T14:05:22-08:00');
```

`$date` would now be `'2009-11-16'`.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this works:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2009-11-16T14:05:22-08:00'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they're all in that format, the easiest way is:

```
$result = substr($timestamp,0,10);
```

Where timestamp is your starting timestamp and result is your modified timestamp.

Comment: I considered that, but won't it be a problem if we were in a month with one digit or in the first few days of this month? Wouldn't that screw it up?

Comment: one-digit months and days will probably have leading zeros, like the '05' in '14:05:22' in your example.

Comment: format that format (ISO8601 with full-date AND full-time), you'll need always to receive a two-digit day and month

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP tagged it as a php and regex question, I'll give him a php and regex answer:

```
$result = preg_replace("/T.*/", "", $timestamp);
```